# How to compare a double value to a list containing double values?

Tags: flutter, dart

For Example, there is a list containing double values:

```
[0.017, 0.068, 0.831, 1.034, 1.475, 1.593, 1.746, 2.017, 2.305, 2.695, 3.051, 3.339, 3.627, 3.763, 3.915, 3.966, 4.644, 4.949, 5.085, 5.203, 5.644, 6.136, 6.271, 6.542, 6.712, 7.085, 7.271, 7.661, 7.831, 8.085, 8.390, 8.915, 9.034, 9.492, 9.508, 9.898, 10.271, 10.610, 10.932, 11.169, 11.203, 11.729, 12.186, 12.288, 12.305, 12.644, 13.051, 13.407, 13.458, 13.729, 14.102, 14.525, 14.542, 14.831, 15.136, 15.559, 15.661, 16.169, 16.220, 16.763, 16.780, 17.119, 17.339, 17.390, 18.254, 18.322, 18.525, 18.746]
```

And there is double value:

```
0.905
```

How can we check which is the first number, that is nearer to **0.905** and greater than **0.905** is contained in the above list in **flutter**?

Comment: Your are mentioned nearer to 0.905. How much nearer to

Comment: The first number which is greater than 0.905 in the list.

Comment: This isn't a comparison; it's a search.

Comment: Ok. I'll check. I think I need to do some updations to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```dart
list.firstWhere(
    (element) => element > 0.905,
    orElse: () => 0,
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets call your list, `_list`, then we can check it like this:

```
var result = _list.where((e) => e >= 0.905).toList();
print("result = $result");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this to get the closest value from a list.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

double getClosest(double value, List<double> valueList) {
    final List<double> diffList = valueList
        .map((i) => (i - value).abs())
        .toList();
    return valueList.elementAt(
      diffList.indexOf(diffList.min),
    );
  }
```

---

To get the first one which is equal or greater do this:

```dart
valueList.where((e) => e >= value).toList()
```

But keep in mind that the `valueList` has to be ordered accordingly.

Comment: for "diffList.min", it is showing min is not defined. I am using flutter sdk version 3.0.2

Comment: `min` is from the package `collection` https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableComparableExtension/min.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the where clause or a for.
check :

```
final List<double> listDouble = [0.017, 0.068, 0.831, 0.905];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < listDouble.length; i++) {
    final double myVar = 0.905;
    
    if (myVar == listDouble[i]){
      print ('$myVar finded in position $i');
    }
    
  }
```

or :

```
final newDoubleList = listDouble.where((e) => e == myVar);
  
  if (newDoubleList.isNotEmpty){
    print('$myVar finded $newDoubleList');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

for simple way you can use following

```
yourDoubleList.where((element) => element > 0.905).toList()
```

advanced way

```
double myDoubleList = [.....]
double value = 0.905 ;

void handle(){
for(double val in myDoubleList  ){
 if(val>=value ){
  print(val) // here you will have all the results that match
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       List<double> samleList=[0.017, 0.068, 0.831, 1.034, 1.475, 1.593, 
          1.746, 2.017, 2.305, 2.695, 3.051, 3.339, 
          3.627, 3.763, 3.915, 3.966, 4.644, 4.949, 5.085, 5.203, 5.644, 6.136, 
          6.271.........];
        
        double minDifference =0, givenNumber =0.905;
        int findingIndex =0;
        for(int i =0; i<samleList.length-1; i++){
        if((samleList[i]>givenNumber) && (samleList[i] - 
 givenNumber<minDifference)){
            minDifference ==samleList[i]-givenNumber;
            findingIndex =i;
        }
                print(samleList[findingIndex]);
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
List list = [
  0.017,
  0.068,
  0.831,
  1.034,
  1.475,
  1.593,
  1.746,
  2.017,
  2.305,
  2.695,
  3.051,
  3.339,
  3.627,
  3.763,
  3.915,
  3.966,
  4.644,
  4.949,
  5.085,
  5.203,
  5.644,
  6.136,
  6.271,
  6.542,
  6.712,
  7.085,
  7.271,
  7.661,
  7.831,
  8.085,
  8.390,
  8.915,
  9.034,
  9.492,
  9.508,
  9.898,
  10.271,
  10.610,
  10.932,
  11.169,
  11.203,
  11.729,
  12.186,
  12.288,
  12.305,
  12.644,
  13.051,
  13.407,
  13.458,
  13.729,
  14.102,
  14.525,
  14.542,
  14.831,
  15.136,
  15.559,
  15.661,
  16.169,
  16.220,
  16.763,
  16.780,
  17.119,
  17.339,
  17.390,
  18.254,
  18.322,
  18.525,
  18.746,
];

final result = list.where((e) => e >= 0.905).toList()[0];

print(result); // 1.034
```